# UIActivityViewController excludedActivityTypes not working with custom UIActivityTypes

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm having trouble excluding custom `UIActivityType`s from `UIActivityViewController`

I have…

```
extension UIActivityType {
    static let fbMessenger = UIActivityType("com.facebook.Messenger.ShareExtension")
    static let telegram = UIActivityType("ph.telegra.Telegraph.Share")
}
```

and then

```
let activityController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: <sharingItems>, applicationActivities: nil)

activityController.excludedActivityTypes = [.postToFacebook, .fbMessenger, .telegram]
present(activityController, animated: true)
```

With the excluded types above, the presented share sheet correctly excludes Facebook, but still shows the 2 custom types (Messenger and Telegraph)

Interestingly, checking the `activityType` in `completionWithItemsHandler` when selecting either of the 2 that I was trying to exclude shows they do have the raw values as above.

Can custom `UIActivityType`s be excluded? Any thought on what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you find a workaround on this?